# SQLiteAsyncConnection inserting multiple row in order?

Tags: c#, sqlite, sqlite.net

I used SQLite before, and adding multiple rows using Insert in a `for` loop was slow. The solution was using a `transaction`.

Now that I am using `SQLiteAsyncConnection` in SQLite.Net (for ORM), I also tried to use a `transaction`. It works but with only one problem. The insert order is not the order of the data.

```
Database.RunInTransactionAsync(
    (SQLiteConnection conn) => {
        foreach (var row in rows)
        {
            conn.InsertOrReplace(row);
        }
        conn.Commit();
    }
);
```

If `rows` contained [1,2,3,4,5,6], the rows in the database was something like [3,1,2,6,4,5]. How can I keep the original order?

Note that I only mean newly inserted rows. Even thought the code is replacing existing rows, when testing there were no existing rows in the database to be replaced.

**PS**: The row has `ID` field which is the `[PrimaryKey]`, but in the `rows` the rows are not sorted by `ID`. It seems that in the database the rows are sorted by `ID`. I do not want it to be sorted by `ID` but the original order to be maintained.

**PS 2**: I need to know the `ID` of the last-inserted row. When viewing the database using a GUI tool like `DB Browser for SQLite` or getting the last item by `LIMIT 1`, it seems the SQLite had automatically sorted the rows by `ID`. I did some Google search and it said by the rules of SQL, when there is no `ORDER BY`, the order of the returned rows are not guaranteed to be the physical order, anyway. Should I create another field and set it as the primary, auto-increasing field?

Currently, `ID` is guaranteed to be unique per row, but 'ID' is part of the data itself, not a field specially added for the use with the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL tables are logically unordered, so if you want a certain order, you always have to use ORDER BY in your queries.

If your data does not contain any values (e.g., timestamp) that corresponds to the insertion order, then you have to use the [rowid](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid), i.e., add a column declared as INTEGER PRIMARY KEY.